# No 1080p@60hz option with nvidia card

Tags: nvidia, display-resolution

My GPU is a GEFORCE 310 512mb HDMi.

My TV is 1080p definitely and has v refresh @ 60hz, which works fine on my xbox and on Windows 7.

The nvidia control panel at first would not do 1080p, but started to do so when I disabled **Force full GPU scaling**.

Now if I lower the refresh rate to 50hz I get 1080p, but when I put it up to 60hz it returns to 1080i.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this...

Open your `xorg.conf` as root.

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

find this line

```
Option  "metamodes" "1920x1080_60i +0+0"
```

Then simply delete the `i` after `60`, save, reboot.

When you log back in you will have 1080p@60hz.

Hope this helps all the people who have this problem.